# path independence of integral of 1-form, what am I missing?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Check whether integral of form: $\frac{y}{x^2+xy+y^2}dx+\frac{-x}{x^2+xy+y^2}dy$ on $R^2$ \ {($0,0$)} is path independent.

The integral of form will be path independent if there exist twice continuously differentiable function $h$ such that partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $x$ is equal to $\frac{y}{x^2+xy+y^2}$ and partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $y$ is equal to $\frac{-x}{x^2+xy+y^2}$ right?

I think such function is $$h(x,y)=\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}\arctan(\frac{\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}x+\frac{\sqrt3}{3}y}{y})$$

So integral of this form is path independent.

However if we consider path $u(t)=(\cos t \sin t)$ ,$t \in [-\pi,\pi]$ then integral of our form is equal to:
$$-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\sin t\cos t}dt$$
which is non zero but the path is closed so we don't have path independence.

What is wrong?

Comment: Where is your $h$ defined?

Comment: So $h$ does not work because is not defined on ${(x,0)}$?

Comment: Yes, and there is no *continuous* way to define it except at the origin.